# Is there an equivalent to 'adb shell input keyboard text' for iOS?

Tags: android, ios, linux, shell

For Android devices, we can use the Android Debug Bridge to invoke the `input` program and send arbitrary strings so that the device will react as though the text was typed by the user on the device.

For iOS, the closest hack I have found is to make [Linux look like a wireless keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229287/how-do-i-make-ubuntu-appear-as-a-bluetooth-keyboard) and that particular hack seems to no longer work with the latest iPad on Ubuntu 13.10. Moreover, even if it worked, it would be less flexible than `input keyboard text` because one could not copy and paste a string to send.

Is there an iOS equivalent to `adb shell input keyboard text`?

Comment: So to clarify this question: is there a terminal command that allows sending text to a focused TextView on iOS? Send down from a Mac to a connected iPhone?

Comment: @JustinAngel, Ideally, I'm trying to find a solution that can send text from any OS, but even one that only works on a Mac is better than nothing.

Comment: Try using Xcode's user interface testing, or Appium http://appium.io

Comment: You can send keystrokes to Simulator.

Comment: there's the libimobiledevice library witch can provide a few tools to begin with, but without jailbreaking it will be mostly impossible

Comment: omg every day on Apple software is one too many. So many hiccups and weird stuff. It's worse than Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Android, there is no way to directly issue text to an iOS device in real time through any sort of command line interface that I am aware of.  If you are trying to do some automation/testing on the device, you can use the xcode command line tools and instruments, but otherwise you are out of luck.

That being said, if you jailbreak your device, you can do anything you'd like, including remote data input.